# Get the Installed / Not Applicable Percentage in WSUS using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script I'm making for a report. I'm having trouble with displaying the **Installed / Not Applicable Percentage** for the updates.

So here's the beginning of the script I'm creating.

```
[void][reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration");
$wsus = [Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.AdminProxy]::getUpdateServer("WSUSSRV",$False);

##Get updates summary per computer##
$computerscope = New-Object Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.ComputerTargetScope;
$updatescope = New-Object Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.UpdateScope;
$wsus.GetSummariesPerComputerTarget($updatescope,$computerscope) | 
Format-Table @{L='ComputerTarget';E={($wsus.GetComputerTarget([guid]$_.ComputerTargetId)).FullDomainName}}, 
@{L='NeededCount';E={($_.DownloadedCount + $_.NotInstalledCount)}},DownloadedCount,NotInstalledCount,InstalledCount,FailedCount,InstalledOrNotApplicablePercentage;
```

The part I'm having trouble with is in the last statement.

```
Format-Table @{L='ComputerTarget';E={($wsus.GetComputerTarget([guid]$_.ComputerTargetId)).FullDomainName}}, 
@{L='NeededCount';E={($_.DownloadedCount + $_.NotInstalledCount)}},DownloadedCount,NotInstalledCount,InstalledCount,FailedCount,InstalledOrNotApplicablePercentage;
```

As you can see, this part will display the table for the report. The last one is ***InstalledOrNotApplicablePercentage***. This is the part I am having trouble displaying. I do not know if this is the correct variable name for that or am I missing something?

Comment: Run `$wsus.GetSummariesPerComputerTarget($updatescope,$computerscope) | Get-Member -Force` to see all members (properties and methods) of the objects being output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `InstalledOrNotApplicablePercentage` property in the object but you can calculate that by adding a computed column which calculates it,like this :

`Format-Table @{L='ComputerTarget';E={($wsus.GetComputerTarget([guid]$_.ComputerTargetId)).FullDomainName}}, 
@{L='NeededCount';E={($_.DownloadedCount + $_.NotInstalledCount)}},DownloadedCount,NotInstalledCount,InstalledCount,FailedCount,@{L= "InstalledOrNotApplicablePercentage";e={(($_.NotApplicableCount + $_.InstalledCount) / ($_.NotApplicableCount + $_.InstalledCount + $_.NotInstalledCount+$_.FailedCount))*100}}`

Answer (score 0):

I think, this is the correct calculation:

```
(($_.NotApplicableCount + $_.InstalledCount) / ($_.NotApplicableCount + $_.InstalledCount + $_.NotInstalledCount+ $_.FailedCount + $_.UnknownCount))*100
```